# R-linear categories

Tags: category-theory

Wikipedia "Preadditive category" and nLab "algebroid" seem to define $R$-linear category as one whose hom-sets are $R$-modules, where those modules are over a COMMUTATIVE ring. Does anybody knows why they require the ring to be commutative? When defining preadditive categories, categories whose hom-sets are abelian groups, no such requirement is made. What is the difference? I anticipate the objection that abelian groups are modules over $\mathbb Z$ which is commutative too. But Wikipedia in the same article, includes the category of (left) modules over a ring $R$ as an example of a preadditive category, and that ring is not required to be commutative.

Comment: The category of left $R$-modules is _not_ $R$-linear in any reasonable sense, unless $R$ is commutative.  This is what Randall's answer is talking about.

Comment: @EricWofsey It's not even clear what it would mean for *any* category to be linear over a noncommutative $R$, no?

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Well, you could ask for bilinearity in a naive sense (linearity in each variable).  It's just that this implies that the action of $R$ factors through the commutator ideal, so you might as well work over $R/[R,R]$ instead of over $R$.

Answer (score 3):

We require `composition of morphisms to be R-bilinear`, i.e. passing through $\hom(A,B)\,\otimes_R\,\hom(B,C)$.

If $R$ were not commutative, we need $\hom(A,B)$ be a right $R$-module and $\hom(B,C)$ a left $R$-module to interpret $R$-bilinearity (or tensor product). 
So that, all homsets need be an $R$-$R$-bimodule, which indeed seem to make sense, and is satisfied automatically if $R$ is commutative. 
But then, one feels that it still should generalize further, allowing $R$-$S$-bimodules in some way..

Now, to keep things in a certain level of generality, we often assume $R$ is commutative.

Comment: @Randall, is there an example of a linear category which is not preaddtive?

Comment: @ Berci, can you explain why if $R$ is not commutative, $R$-bilinearity requires $hom(A,B)$ to be a right $R$-module and $hom(B,C)$ to be a left module. I know very little about module theory.

Comment: @alexanderyaacov that's when the tensor product over $R$ is defined.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general notion of what it means for a category $C$ to be [enriched](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) over another category $M$, meaning at a minimum that all of the homs in $C$ are objects in $M$. But you need more than this: to define composition you need to explain what it means to write down a morphism called "composition," which means you need to explain what its source and target are, as objects in $M$. This means $M$ needs to be a [monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category), equipped with some notion of "tensor product" $\otimes$ of its objects, so that you can define composition as a morphism

$$\text{Hom}(a, b) \otimes \text{Hom}(b, c) \to \text{Hom}(a, c)$$

in $M$.

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then the category $\text{Mod}(R)$ of $R$-modules naturally acquires a (symmetric) monoidal structure given by the tensor product $\otimes_R$ over $R$. However, if $R$ is noncommutative, and we consider, say, left modules, there is not even a monoidal structure, since one can't take the tensor product of a left module and a left module. So it doesn't make sense to consider enrichments over $\text{Mod}(R)$ when $R$ is noncommutative, at least without specifying some other monoidal structure.

> But Wikipedia in the same article, includes the category of (left) modules over a ring $R$ as an example of a preadditive category, and that ring is not required to be commutative.

That's irrelevant; preadditive categories are only required to be enriched over abelian groups, or $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is always commutative.

Comment: is there a category which is preadditive but not $R$-linear, or $R$-linear but not preadditive, for some cummutative ring $R$?

Comment: @alexanderyaacov: being preadditive or $R$-linear is a structure, not a property, so it doesn't make grammatical sense to ask whether a category is preadditive or $R$-linear. (The confusing thing is that being additive *is* a property; that is, it does make sense to ask whether a category is additive.) Every $R$-linear category can be equipped with the structure of a preadditive category in a natural way, by considering the underlying abelian group of each $R$-module. Many preadditive categories cannot be equipped with the structure of an $R$-linear category in a way which is consistent...

Comment: ...with the forgetful functor I just defined. For the sake of simplicity, consider one-object categories; a one-object preadditive category is a ring and a one-object $R$-linear category is an $R$-algebra. Then I'm looking for a ring $S$ which can't be given the structure of an $R$-algebra for some commutative ring $R$. Take, for example, $S = \mathbb{Z}, R = \mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: To Qiaochu Yuan, so you are saying that when Mac Lane page 28 and Wikipedia "Preadditive category" list $R-Mod$ among the preadditive categories, they mean forget the ring $R$ and consider the $R$-modules as $\mathbb Z$-modules. Correct?

Comment: @alexanderyaacov: no, they mean that the set of module homomorphisms between two modules has an abelian group structure (given by pointwise addition).

Comment: But the module homomorphisms also has a module structure. So they mean forget the module structure of the module homomorphisms and consider only the abelian group structure?

Comment: @alexanderyaacov: no, that’s not true unless $R$ is commutative.

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly is not true. Mac Lane and wikipedia don't say anything about $R$ being commutative or not.

Comment: to Qiaochu Yuan. I understand now what is not true. Thanks.

Comment: To Qiaochu Yuan, what is the $R$-algebra ${\mathbb F}_2$? By the way, why putting the @ sign before QiaochuYuan doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the reason is in module theory.  For $R$-modules $M$ and $N$, the set $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,N)$ is naturally an abelian group.  You'd prefer it to be an $R$-module since that's the category from which $M$ and $N$ came.  This is true if $R$ is commutative.  In particular, if $M$ is an $(R,S)$-bimodule then 
$\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,N)$ has a natural $S$-module structure, and there is a similar story in the $N$-variable.  But, if $R$ is commutative, everything works out to be the same in both variables and (a) $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,N)$ is an $R$-module and (b) this structure is compatible in both slots.